# HTML table to image

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

So I've got this web page, and in it various tables are dinamicaly populated with php data. Once they show in the web page it looks like this:

[image: Several tables dinamically populated with PHP]

I want to have a button inside those divs, so a diferent button to every table. That button should download the table in .png or .jpg format. As you can see the tables are scrollable, but I'd like to have all of the table displayed in the image if possible.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about creating a PDF of it, [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) seems to be a nice tool to me.

Comment: check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591097/save-html-table-as-an-image

Comment: I'm trying get it do with html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) but its giving me an error: 'Uncaught TypeError: node.setAttribute is not a function' any one knows how to solve it? @GuilhermeSilva

Comment: Its quite hard to say anything without a seeing the code, but there is this link that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686504/typeerror-node-setattribute-is-not-a-function

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva it doesn't get errors but it doesn't download as well... You still want a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah sure, if you can, I would like to see and try to help =D

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva https://jsfiddle.net/hu5vfo84/

That is essencially what I'm doing, I can't incorporate the html2canvas file so yeah... the error I get now is that window.location.href is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it using jquery/php logic is to send a request with the table data to your php and then process and create a pdf with something like http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php or http://www.fpdf.org/. I think you cant use a screenshot like function just because you want something that is not visible.
here a [basic example for creating a table inside the pdf](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/3/)

Comment: Oh was not thinking about something like editing a canvas... lets edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for answering I'm trying to get it to convert to image directly, using html2canvas, if I'm not able to do it I may use your suggestion.